# Como converter data e hora com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma *string* de data no seguinte formato:

> `Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM`.

Preciso converter a data para o seguinte formato:

> `11/12/2017`

e a hora para este formato:

> `01:00`.

Eu pensei em tratar a data por meio de uma condicional e substituir os meses conforme o desejado, mas isso não irá funcionar para a hora, pois são muitas variações. Deve haver uma função no JavaScript que faz essa conversão, como posso converter data e hora com JavaScript?

Comment: Para manipulações com formatos de data e hora eu recomendo usar o componente Moment js que já faz de forma segura e sem chance de erros de cálculo e etc. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: com o Moment basta você chamar dessa forma: moment("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM", "lll").format("L") e ai adicionar a hora ou usar um formato customizado.

Comment: A questão aqui é que como está vindo em format inglês "Dec" o Date.parse falha porque ele estará configurado para o Brasil, então você vai ter que fazer mesmo um código na mão, construindo uma data na mão baseado nas abreviações de mês em inglês :-\

Comment: Fazer isso na unha é um tiro no pé :-(

Comment: O foco principal da dificuldade na pergunta, acho eu, estaria no formato  da data recebida que não é um formato válido, portanto, não acho que seja `possível duplicata`, pois que, esse problema pontual não está sendo abordado nos outros posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Se a data está vindo nesses formatos**

`Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM`  ou  `Dec 11, 2017 01:00PM`

**temos que tratá-la para um formato válido (AM ou PM separados por um espaço)**

`Dec 11, 2017 01:00 AM` ou  `Dec 11, 2017 01:00 PM`

E isto pode ser feito usando o método [**substr()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)  que retorna os caracteres em uma string começando na localização especificada através do número especificado de caracteres:

```
var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM");
recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);
```

> Feita a devida formatação, é possível encontrar vários posts que resolverão sua dificuldade

toLocaleString() - função nativa do Javascript - string de data/hora no formato localizado no seu sistema

```js
var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM");

recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);

var data = new Date(recebida);

var resultado = data.toLocaleString();

console.log (resultado);
```

> Exemplo 1 - Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM
>
> ```js
> var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM");
>
> recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);
>
> var data = new Date(recebida);
>
> var resultado = data.toLocaleString();
>
> console.log (resultado);
> ```
>
> Exemplo 2 - Dec 11, 2017 01:00PM
>
> ```js
> var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00PM");
>
> recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);
>
> var data = new Date(recebida);
>
> var resultado = data.toLocaleString();
>
> console.log (resultado);
> ```
>
> Exemplo 3 - Se não quiser apresentar os segundos faça 
>   `resultado = resultado.substr(0,16);`

```js
var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00PM");

recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);

var data = new Date(recebida);

var resultado = data.toLocaleString();

resultado = resultado.substr(0,16);

console.log (resultado);
```

**Sem configurações do local**

```js
    var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM");
    recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);
    
    var data = new Date(recebida);
    var dia = data.getDate();
    if (dia.toString().length == 1)
      dia = "0"+dia;
    var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
    if (mes.toString().length == 1)
      mes = "0"+mes;
    var ano = data.getFullYear();
    var hora = data.getHours();
    if (hora.toString().length == 1)
      hora = "0"+hora;
    var minutos = data.getMinutes();
    if (minutos.toString().length == 1)
      minutos = "0"+minutos;
    console.log (dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano+ " "+hora+":"+minutos);
```

**Ou resumidamente**

```js
var recebida = ("Dec 11, 2017 01:00PM");
recebida = recebida.substr(0,18)+" "+recebida.substr(-2);
    
var data = new Date(recebida);
    
var dataFormatada = ("0" + data.getDate()).substr(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + "/" + data.getFullYear() +" " + ("0"+ data.getHours()).substr(-2)+":"+("0"+ data.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    
console.log(dataFormatada);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Funciona perfeitamente aqui no console, mas no aplicativo Code (zapier.com/help/code/#requiring-or-using-external-libraries‌​) do Zapier o output fica nesse formato: `Mon Dec 11 2017`. Acredito ser por causa das configurações do local, ao usar o `toLocaleString()`, pois a empresa fica no USA.

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa, veja se a alternativa `Sem configurações do local` na resposta atende!

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou plenamente! Muito grato Leo.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o componente Moment.js fica muito fácil.

Basta baixar ou linkar a biblioteca em:
https://momentjs.com/

E usar o código em javascript:

```
var data = moment("Dec 11, 2017 01:00AM", "lll").format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
```

Vai escrever '11/12/2017 01:00' na variável `data`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas estou utilizando o aplicativo Code (https://zapier.com/help/code/#requiring-or-using-external-libraries) da ferramenta online Zapier, e nesse aplicativo não consigo linkar bibliotecas externas.

Comment: Você pode carregar via javascript, não vejo como o aplicativo pode te bloquear. :-\

Comment: Na documentação consta o seguinte:

"Infelizmente, você não pode exigir bibliotecas externas ou instalar ou importar bibliotecas comumente referidas como "módulos npm". Somente a biblioteca padrão node.js e o fetch pacote estão disponíveis no aplicativo Código. fetch já está incluído no namespace."

Comment: Essa data neste formato vem de onde exatamente? quem está formatando desta forma?

Comment: Ela vem da agenda Google, e o aplicativo da agenda do Zapier que faz a formatação.

Comment: @Zorkind Apesar de estar correta, quando uma pergunta é marcada com a *tag* [tag:javascript], subentendesse que o AP, deseja uma resposta com JavaScript puro, sem uso de nenhuma biblioteca ou API de terceiros.

Comment: acho que essa tag é abrangente demais para dizer que é somente javascript puro.

Comment: Quem votou negativo, por favor, explicar o motivo.